# SAP BOE Webi Track Changes features identifies changes as Delete/insert instead of change

Tags: webi

Trying to use SAP BOE Webi's Track changes feature and it is not working as expected.

I created a simple two column report and turned on track changes since the last refresh.  Then I updated the value of one of the columns on one of the rows in the database and refreshed the report.  It shows that change as a delete and add instead of a change.